# "That's okay" to mean "no" or "don't bother"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, dialects

Growing up, I became accustomed to using the phrase "that's okay" to mean "no" or "don't bother."  For example:

> **Waitress**: [Yous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yous) guys want any dessert?
> **Patron** [shaking head to mean no]: That's okay.
> **Waitress**: Here's the check then, hun.

In other words, the patron is really trying to say, "That's okay, *but I am already full*."

Later on in life, when traveling to areas with other dialects of English, I was often met with confusion when trying to use that phrase to mean "no".  When I got to thinking about it, the phrase itself is quite ambiguous, because it is unclear to what "that" refers.  In fact, "that's okay" could very well be taken to mean "yes" in the above scenario, if interpreted literally.  I have since taught myself to avoid this usage.

Having first learned English in the [Philadelphia dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia_accent), I attributed this weird usage as a regional fluke, like our use of "[anymore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_anymore)", [*et al*](http://archives.citypaper.net/articles/081497/article008.shtml).  However, I have since heard other people in other dialects using this phrase to mean "no".

**Questions**: Is this usage of "that's okay" a regionalism?  Is its etymology as simple as just dropping the end of the phrase, *e.g.*, "That's okay<strike>, *but I am already full*</strike>," or is its etymology more complex?

**Edit:** This is completely anecdotal, but I seemed to meet the most resistance to this construction on the West coast of the US, and particularly in the Pacific Northwest, *e.g.*,

> **Waitress**: Would you like any dessert?
> **Me** [shaking head to mean no]: That's okay.
> **Waitress**: Does that mean "yes" or "no"‽

Comment: I remember being told that if you were offered something in France, the answer "merci!" ("thanks") meant "No, thanks".

Comment: In france we say "non merci" for "no thanks", simply.

Comment: @BiAiB: But you usually say "s'il vous plait" to mean "yes, thank you", right? Would people just say "merci" to mean "yes"?

Comment: @Peter yes then no

Comment: In Japan, people often say "hai" (usually meaning "yes") to mean "I heard you" rather than "yes, I will." For example, "Please have some more cake." "Hai" here might mean, "I heard your offer (but I won't necessarily have more cake)."

Comment: @BiAiB: I expect that @Colin is operationally correct, then, in that if you say *merci* to a waiter in France, they are likely to hear *non merci* (it certainly sounds a lot more like that than *s'il vous plaît*) and not give you what you thought you were asking for.

Comment: @Peter indeed, if you answer "merci" shaking the head horizontally, they will probably assume "non merci". but if you're asked "Voulez vous voir la carte des vins" and answer "merci" with no negative indication in your body language, they will surely bring it to you, assuming "oui merci". Better use "s'il vous plait" and "non merci", or "c'est bon"[less formal] which can be used like "that's okay" in OP's dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t think it’s a regionalism. I’m from Tennessee and it sounds perfectly natural to me. And there’s evidence from the movies:

> Nicky: [after being sick in Andy's face] I'm sorry. I'll still have sex with you if you want.
>   Andy Stitzer: **That's OK.**
>   —[The 40-Year-Old Virgin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405422/quotes)

(Of course, real people don’t talk like movie characters, but here the joke only works if the audience understands “That’s OK” the way you and I do.)

Apparently Canadians say it too:

> Bob: Sorry I ralphed, Pam.
>   Pam: You shouldn't have had that chocolate milk.
>   Bob: I know.  Sorry about your sweater.  You can take it out of my pay if you want.
>   Pam: **That's OK.**
>   Bob: Geez, you're real nice.  If I didn't have puke breath I'd kiss you.
>   —[Strange Brew](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/s/strange-brew-script.html)

It might be a North Americanism, I guess, but I suspect it’s not even that, just the sort of counterintuitive idiom non-native speakers naturally have trouble with.

Comment: "She was like, oh, [no, that's ok](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=10866576)" — I wouldn't blink hearing this.

Comment: I'm from the US Pacific Northwest, and it sounds normal to me.  I wouldn't question whether it meant yes or no - it means no.  There is an inflection as it is said, which emphasises the no answer.

Comment: We use this in the UK too, so it's not just an Americanism. Having said that, I think saying "I'm fine" is more common over here; it's quite British :)

Answer (score 2):

I use this construction, and the related "I'm good", and I'm from England. I have friends who also use the same constructions. While I wouldn't say that it's a universal usage, I would expect people here to understand it.

Comment: And here. Although sometimes "That's okay" mean piss off and don't bother me anymore - in a polite way :O